# Why does Pandas say this data frame has only one column?

Tags: python

I began a python course in linear and logistic regression but I am encountering what is probably a stupid error. I have to work with this data frame:

http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/wine-quality/winequality-red.csv

And this is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rwq = pd.read_csv('*filepath*/winequality-red.csv')
rows = len(rwq.index)
cols = rwq.shape[1]
```

When I print rows and cols, rows correctly prints 1599 but for some reason cols always equals 1 (when in fact they are 12).

I also tried 'len(rwq.columns)' and I still get 1.

Am I doing something wrong or is the problem with the file provided?

Comment: check if the separator is the correct one. By default it takes `,` as the separator. Your file might not be comma separated

Comment: There is separator `;` so need `rwq = pd.read_csv('*filepath*/winequality-red.csv', sep=';')`

Comment: Thanks, adding sep=';' fixed it!!